# "LapackError: Parameter a has non-native byte order in lapack_lite.dgesdd" when importing from Matlab files

Tags: matlab, numpy, python-2.7, scipy

After importing [this data file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xkqq1vsubyz8aa/dati-esercizio1.mat) from Matlab with `scipy.io.loadmat`, things appeared to work fine until we tried to calculate the conditioning number of one of the matrixes within.

Here's the minimum amount of code that reproduces for us:

```
import scipy
import numpy

stuff = scipy.io.loadmat("dati-esercizio1.mat")
numpy.linalg.cond(stuff["A"])
```

Here's the extended stacktrace courtesy of iPython:

```
In [3]: numpy.linalg.cond(A)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LapackError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/snip/<ipython-input-3-15d9ef00a605> in <module>()
----> 1 numpy.linalg.cond(A)

/snip/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in cond(x, p)
   1409     x = asarray(x) # in case we have a matrix
   1410     if p is None:
-> 1411         s = svd(x,compute_uv=False)
   1412         return s[0]/s[-1]
   1413     else:

/snip/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in svd(a, full_matrices, compute_uv)
   1313         work = zeros((lwork,), t)
   1314         results = lapack_routine(option, m, n, a, m, s, u, m, vt, nvt,
-> 1315                                  work, -1, iwork, 0)
   1316         lwork = int(work[0])
   1317         work = zeros((lwork,), t)

LapackError: Parameter a has non-native byte order in lapack_lite.dgesdd
```

All obvious ideas (like flattening and reshaping the matrix or recreating the matrix from scratch reassigning it element by element) failed. How can I want to massage the data, then, in order to make it more agreeable with numpy?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug, fixed some time ago: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/235

Workaround:

```
np.linalg.cond(stuff['A'].newbyteorder('='))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
In [33]: stuff = loadmat('dati-esercizio1.mat')

In [34]: a = stuff['A']

In [35]: try: np.linalg.cond(a)
   ....: except: print "Fail!"
Fail!

In [36]: b = np.array(a, dtype='>d')

In [37]: np.linalg.cond(b)
Out[37]: 62493201976.673141

In [38]: np.all(a == b)  # Verify they hold the same data.
Out[38]: True
```

Answer (score -1):

Apparently it's something wrong with the byte order (endianness?) of *each number in the resulting ndarray* and not just with the ndarray object itself.

Something like this but more elegant should do the trick:

```
n, m = A.shape()
B = numpy.empty_like(A)

for i in xrange(n):
  for j in xrange(m):
    B[i,j] = float(A[i,j])

del A
B = A

print numpy.linalg.cond(A) # 62493210091.354507
```

(For some reason an in-place replacement still gives that error - so there's something wrong with the byte order of the whole object, too.)

Comment: There are no individual number objects in an ndarray --- the ndarray has a single byte order which applies to all its contents.